# Odd Echo that comes and goes

Tags: analog

I'm doing live video with an analog video system that has an analog to digital converter after all the mixing switching is done and somewhere in my system I'm getting an odd echo/clicking.

The waveform of the clicks looks like a half SIN curve as apposed to a flat line like I would expect from digital issues.

Are there good ways of determining the cause of clicking?

Answer (score 1):

It's the clocking. You need to feed a system clock to the ADC so that the converter feeds digital audio into the system in sync with the main system clock. Either that or use the ADC as the master clock.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed the ADC was the master clock but I'll look into it more.